# Problem accessing English Environment Agency API with QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, ows

I am a GIS novice attempting to use QGIS (version 3.12.3-București) to link to a UK Environment Agency flood zone dataset using the various data links provided here:

https://data.gov.uk/dataset/cf494c44-05cd-4060-a029-35937970c9c6/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2

Using the base WFS/WMS URLs provided just returns an error, but following the advice at 'https://support.environment.data.gov.uk/hc/en-gb/articles/360001340657-How-do-i-add-WFS-layers-in-ArcGIS-and-QGIS-' and adding parameters, I do manage to import some partial data using this URL:

https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=Flood_Map_for_Planning_Rivers_and_Sea_Flood_Zone_2&BBOX=450660,332709,461502,347119,EPSG:27700&srsName=EPSG:27700

The layer data imported isn’t correct (it doesn’t match any watercourses and only covers a small area near Nottingham - see screenshot), but it at least shows that the API link works!

[image: Screenshot]

Does anyone have any experience of accessing this specific data using and has made it work correctly with QGIS, or can at least suggest what else I might try?

Comment: I didn't try very hard, but couldn't get the WMS working, but the WFS works fine (https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2/wfs).  Make sure you add it as a WFS, not a WMS.

Comment: `https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2/wms?` is WMS end point, and `https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2/wfs?` is WFS end point.  Browsing to either without request parameters will give warning `Query Parameters must include Request`

Comment: UK? Environment Agency is only England but sponsored by the UK Government. (Scotland and Wales have their versions and share their data slightly differently).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had gone a fair bit of the way. Consider the final URL carefully: https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=GetFeature&TYPENAME=Flood_Map_for_Planning_Rivers_and_Sea_Flood_Zone_2&BBOX=450660,332709,461502,347119,EPSG:27700&srsName=EPSG:27700

Everything after `?` is a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) that serve to constrain or increase the specifity of what that service is giving back to you. Importantly, the `BBOX=450660,332709,461502,347119` part is restricting the extent of the output: this is why you only get partial data.

If you just take the root of that URL (i.e. https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2/wfs) you can use that in QGIS. Right click on `WFS / OGC API - Features` > New Connection > Name it whatever you like > Enter `https://environment.data.gov.uk/spatialdata/flood-map-for-planning-rivers-and-sea-flood-zone-2/wfs` in the URL > Press OK > It should display (it might prompt you about doing a coordinate transformation too, just click OK and accept whatever it offers to do).

Note that there's a fair bit of data there and it might take some time to download.

This kind of service is generally known as a "web feature service", or WFS. Searching for that will probably help you.

[image]

Comment: The WFS does not match up, neither with different datum transformations, not axis inversion. The WMS layer has perfect match when use with `?crs=EPSG:227700` attached to the base URL, and according QGIS project CRS

Comment: Agreed. You could try asking about this problem on the Defra Data Services Forum:

https://support.environment.data.gov.uk/hc/en-gb/community/topics/360000549291-Data-users-All-other-data-services

Comment: when you add the base map you probably need to change the project projection to EPSG:3857 - QGIS will then make the rest line up to the base map for you

Comment: I have followed the @Alphabetasoup response and this seems like a more robust approach than I was previously trying (Layer -> Add Layer -> Add Vector Layer). I can make the data connections using the Browser as both WMS and WFS.

With respect to displaying adding the data as layers, WMS doesn't display anything and WFS only displays as mirrored across a line that runs from southeast to northwest. Playing with inversion options doesn't fix this and adding '?crs=EPSG:227700' doesn't help either.

I have tried asking the question at support.environment.data.go.uk and a response is awaited.

Comment: ...I also have no problem adding the downloaded shapefiles for the same data in the correct locations. It is just the WFS/WMS links that are causing me problems. I am looking to access the live data to make sure I am always using the most up-to-date information without having to constantly check for updates.

Comment: @Jinks note that the WMS service usually has a scale dependency, so it will only show at scales larger than e.g. 1:150.000

Comment: @geozelot Ah, yes I see that now and I can add WMS data in the right place and the above comments all make perfect sense to me now. This has solved my problems for flood zone information, but not for watercourse alignment data (which I would like to change the symbology of to create thicker line weights), so this now appears to be either a problem with the base data or with QGIS not being able to invert the information properly with respect to WFS data. I guess my current workaround here is to just use downloaded (or WMS) data.

Comment: Weird. I just tried reconnecting to the WFS using inverted axis and it now works! Nothing appears to have changed with the source data and comments from @geozelot seems to confirm that I just wasn't doing things incorrectly. For reference, the specific data I was trying to access as WFS is here: 'https://data.gov.uk/dataset/4ae8ba46-f9a4-47d0-8d93-0f93eb494540/statutory-main-river-map'.